# Not changing the chat message bubble color after applying the new color CSS class using jquery

Tags: smooch

I am changing the chat bubble color using the css class with jquery. its working fine when its loaded at the first time. but when we are sending new message this new CSS class is not applying on that.

We play around it and found that if we applied the new CSS class on `message:send` event then it will work. so i did that. but its not working on first message send.

When we are sending 2nd message then the first one is updating.

I am using the following codes in the `init` and `message:send` event.

```
$('#sk-holder #sk-container #sk-conversation .sk-row.sk-right-row .sk-msg').addClass('newClass');
```

I am doing it for web only.

Answer (score 1):

You can now change the bubble color directly from your account settings at https://app.smooch.io under Web. This new feature is supported since 2.2.3 and is available on the CDN.